# Where to find real estate holdings of a REIT?

Tags: reit

I'm analyzing REITs and would like to look at the property holdings. If this information is not in the annual report, where else can I find it?
Are there public available regulatory documents that need to be filed by the REIT on its holdings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it isn't in the offer document, the only other way is probably trawl through the net.

I just checked [HANSTEEN](http://www.hansteen.co.uk/property-search) on their website and got the properties they own in UK and Belgium.

Now if I check an [ETF](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239482/ishares-cohen-steers-reit-etf) I can see they have quite a number of holdings, so you might need to trawl through their websites.

But are you sure you cannot find them in the annual statements. I checked one from [SPG](http://nasdaqomx.mobular.net/nasdaqomx/7/3533/5040/document_0/Simon%202016%20Annual%20Report-processed.pdf) and their properties are listed there.

Comment: Thank you for forcing me to recheck. It was not in the annual report but there was a separate information statement on the website that had the details.